# Wireshark разница между двумя фильтрами

Tags: фильтры, трафик, фильтрация, wireshark

Фильтр 1 : !(ip.addr == X.X.X.X)
Фильтр 2 :   ip.addr != X.X.X.X
В обеих фильтрах правое выражение одинаковое.
В чем между ними разница?
А разница есть, т.к. один и тот же буфер после фильтрации выдает разные результаты.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разница между ними есть. `!(ip.addr == X.X.X.X)` значит `! (ip.src == X.X.X.X or ip.dst == X.X.X.X)`, то есть показать весь трафик кроме источника **или** назначения X.X.X.X. А `ip.addr != X.X.X.X` значит  ip.src != X.X.X.X or ip.dst != X.X.X.X, то есть показать весь трафик кроме источника **и** назначения X.X.X.X. Подробнее про фильтры можно здесь почитать https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters#Examples

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас посмотрю.  
А если не учитывать что эти два выражения фильтры в wireshark, а просто это условия в обычном коде, или даже алгебре логики, то эти два выражения эквиваленты? А то я строил таблицы истинности, у меня выходило, что выражения эквиваленты.

Comment: Тут специфика именно wireshark, в документации примечание есть. Там говорится, что фильтр `ip.addr !=` не правильный.

Comment: Так, если я правильно понял, то оба этих фильтра отсеивают переписку между мной и узлом у которого ip равен X.

Т.е. эти фильтры отсеивают те пакеты которые я шлю узлу с ip X, и отсеивают те пакеты, которые узел с ip X присылает мне.
Да?

Причем, второй фильтр это частный случай первого фильтра.  
Первый фильтр так же отсеивает переписку меня с самим собой.  
    
А второй фильтр отсеивает переписку только меня с самим собой.

Comment: Да, я правильно понял. Я насчет предыдущего комментария.